# chrony and gpsd: socket or PPS connection

Tags: linux, time-synchronization, gps, chrony

I've try to get high precision time from gps receiver GlobalSat BU-353s4 (`/dev/ttyUSB0`) through `gpsd` in Raspberry PI with ArchLinux.

`/etc/chrony.conf` contains:

```
refclock SHM 0  delay 0.5 refid NEMA
refclock SHM 1 offset 0.0 delay 0.1 refid PPS
refclock SOCK /var/run/chrony.ttyUSB0.sock delay 0.0 refid SOCK
```

I've get time through NEMA (**SHM 0 source**) (but with low accuracy).

`gpsd` did not find kernel PPS extension, as the result **SHM 1 source** did not working:

```
gpsd:WARN: KPPS:/dev/ttyUSB0 kernel PPS unavailable, PPS accuracy will suffer
```

But `lsmod` shows that pps modules is loaded:

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
pps_ldisc               2305  0
pps_core                7982  1 pps_ldisc
```

**Socket source** also did not working:

```
# chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 9
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
#x NEMA                          0   4   377    18   -532ms[ -532ms] +/-  252ms
#? SOCK                          0   4     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
```

But `gpsd -N -D8 /dev/ttyUSB0` shows that sock file is opened:

```
gpsd:RAW: PPS:/dev/ttyUSB0 using chrony socket: /var/run/chrony.ttyUSB0.sock
```

**The question**: How to make kernel PPS available for `gpsd` or make the socket work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, pps is NOT available via USB.  You need to use a direct connection.  USB is polled and thus cannot provide an accurate enough signal.  I learned this trying to set up some Windows boxes at work.

Your GPS module doesn't have PPS out, it will be on a separate pin or connector.  This needs to be connected to a GPIO pin on the Pi.

I have just set up two Pi's for ntp and this is the site I used for reference using the Adafruit GPS module. (Picture with blue box)

```
http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-NTP.html
```

I fought with the second one because I didn't have a GPS lock as I needed a second antenna and it was raining outside.

Comment: The BU-353-S4 actually does have a PPS output, but it's on the inside. The 6 pin connector has one unpopulated pin. It's also 1.8V logic level. It's also driving the LED and the voltages are a bit off. It's also 0.5 Hz. If you're still undeterred, snip out the LED for better levels and use a level shifter to hit the RPi.